# Validação de um Select Option Dinamico

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Galera preciso de uma super ajuda!

Preciso validar um SELECT OPTION que é gerado dinamicamente:

```
                            <table class="small-grid" style="margin-top:18px;">
                                <?php $i=1; foreach ($ImportFields as $EachField): ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;"><?php echo $EachField; ?></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select name="MatchedFields<?php echo $i; ?>" id="MatchedFields<?php echo $i; ?>">
                                                <option value="0"><?php InterfaceLanguage('Screen', '1183'); ?></option>
                                                <?php foreach ($CustomFields as $EachCustomField): ?>
                                                    <option value="CustomField<?php echo $EachCustomField['CustomFieldID']; ?>"><?php echo $EachCustomField['FieldName']; print_r($EachCustomField['CustomFieldID']); ?></option>
                                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
                            </table>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O conteúdo do SELECT OPTION é igual em todos os campos.

O que eu preciso: fazer uma validação para que o usuario não selecione o mesmo item duas vezes, exibindo alguma mensagem ou um alerta avisando que o item "Email"(EXEMPLO) já foi selecionado no SELECT OPTION anterior.

Alguém pode me ajudar com alguma sugestão?

Comment: E quando mostra o aviso o que acontece com as opções duplicadas? muda a primeira, a ultima ou as duas?

Comment: Sergio, ele deve continuar na mesma pagina, ate que preencha todos os campos sem que nenhum se repita, deu para entender?

Comment: @Vitor Você conseguiu resolver o problema?

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria da seguinte forma:

Defina a função count dentro do escopo de um objeto do tipo Array

```
    // Definição de função no escopo de Array para contar 
    // quantas vezes um elemento aparece no conjunto.
    // Uso: var x = ['a','a','b','c'];
    //      x.count('a'); // retorna 2
    Array.prototype.count = function (what) {
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            if (this[i] === what) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Crie um array para guardar as opções selecionadas

```
var opts = [];
```

Coloque um evento de change nos seus selects

```
$('select[id*="MatchedFields"]').on('change', function (){
    if (!(opts.count($(this).val()) > 0)) {
        opts.push($(this).val());
    }else{
      // exibe uma mensagem de campo inválido
    }
});
```